# How to pass a parameter "abc" : "12" to a cucumber(Java) step

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I want to pass strings from a step as shown in the code below:

test.feature

```
Then I pass a string ""abc" : "12""
```

test.java

```
@Then("I pass a string\"([^]*)\"")
public void function(String data)
{
    System.out.println(data)
}
```

the string which I am passing (""abc" : "12"") is matching with the regular expression (\"([^]*)\") . So ideally the expectation is that the function should print

```
"abc" : "12"
```

But the function call is not happening. Is there anything wrong in my regular expression...what can be done to achieve the expected result (that is printing "abc" : "12")

I am a newbie to cucumber java, pardon me if my question sounds dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression doesn't match the text since you've got a space not accounted for just before the first quote.

Add the missing space and use `.+` to match the group:

```
@Then("I pass a string \"(.+)\"")
public void function(String data)
{
    System.out.println(data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Florent ... This Regular expression perfectly matched my requirement . But I didn't understand about the space you are talking about...

Comment: The text `I pass a string "...` compared to `I pass a string"...` has an additional quotation just after the word string.